# Is there a python equivalent to the Unix '$?' command?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unix, fastjson

I am using [fastjsonschema](https://horejsek.github.io/python-fastjsonschema/modules/fastjsonschema.html) for validating json records against its schema.
Some thing like this:

```
import fastjsonschema
validate = fastjsonschema.compile({'type': 'string'})
validate('hello')
```

If the json is valid, it returns the json string else return the error string. I just want to check if the json is valid or not. For this I can do a workaround of comparing output of the validate method and the json input.

But I want something cleaner. May be something like '$?' in unix or something better.

Could you suggest me?

Comment: "else return the error string" - no, in case of validation failure it raises `JsonSchemaException` (which is a very clean and correct way to handle it)

Comment: Read the docs: `Exception JsonSchemaException is raised from generated funtion when validation fails (data do not follow the definition).` From: https://horejsek.github.io/python-fastjsonschema/index.html#fastjsonschema.compile

Comment: Thanks @rdas Being a newbie to Python did not gave attention to that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan Being a newbie to Python did not gave attention to that. Thanks.

Comment: `$?` exists because you can't just write `x = validate()` like you can in Python.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://horejsek.github.io/python-fastjsonschema/index.html#fastjsonschema.compile), there seem to be two different exceptions thrown in case of error:

- **[JsonSchemaDefinitionException](https://horejsek.github.io/python-fastjsonschema/index.html#fastjsonschema.JsonSchemaDefinitionException)**, when the definition is bad
- **[JsonSchemaException](https://horejsek.github.io/python-fastjsonschema/index.html#fastjsonschema.JsonSchemaException)**, when the data is not matching the definition

In Python, you can simply wrap that with a [try ... except block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) like this:

```
try:
    validate = fastjsonschema.compile({'type': 'string'})
    validate(1)
except (fastjsonschema.JsonSchemaException, fastjsonschema.JsonSchemaDefinitionException):
    print("Uh oh ...")
```